# Why won't my javascript function run?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My javascript plots different points on a Google maps map after retrieving the lat long etc. from my xml file. However, when a marker is clicked, it is supposed to show an info window with the location name (which it does). The problem is that the function `stoptimes()` which is called to get the times for the bus stop clicked, is not being called. I don't know why this is. I have used syntax validators to check it and it reports no error message. Any ideas as to what it could be?

```
function stoptimes(stop) {
  downloadiv("./times.php?stop=" + stop, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("weather");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("arrival");
      document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = name;
    }
  });
}

function downloadiv(url, callback) {
  var requesta = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  requesta.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (requesta.readyState == 4) {
      requesta.onreadystatechange = donada;
      callback(requesta, requesta.status);
    }
  };

  requesta.open('GET', url, true);
  requesta.send(null);    
}

function donada() {}

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5, -8),
    zoom: 7,
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("stop-locations.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var location = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var lat=markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
      var lng=markers[i].getAttribute("lng");
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>";
      var stopid = markers[i].getAttribute("stopid");
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:point,
        map: map
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, stopid);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, stopid) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    stoptimes(stopid);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your functions is being called so your code isn't doing anything.
I think you forgot to call bindInfoWindow

Comment: No, BindInfoWindow is being called right above where it is defined. It is called when the body loads (which isn't shown above). The bind info window definitely works because the info window appears in the google map when a marker is clicked.

Comment: If bindInfoWindow is called then there's either an error in your callback before the call to stoptimes or stoptimes is called.

You should try and add a console.log at the beginning of stoptimes to be sure it's not called

Comment: So what just put "console.log()" inside the function?

Comment: Ya I tried alerting the window and still no response, the stoptimes() function doesn't appear to be called?

Comment: Add 

    console.log("Test");

inside both stoptimes and bindInfoWorker ( just before the call to stoptimes) to figure what's going wrong

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. i was redefining the function later and that wasn't calling stoptimes();

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `load()` anywhere in your code?
Did you mean `load()` to be `onload()`, as in `window.onload`?